# Spring Batch to read and retry on failuire over a xml list(and not entire file)

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

i have a sample input file like shown below. I would like spring batch to process it and retry on an exception. However the processing and retry shoud not be on the entire input, but the at the list(record) level. For instance while processing record 1001,1002 & 1003, if 1002 fails then spring batch should retry it three times before proceeding to 1003.

```
<company>
    <record refId="1001">
        <name>mkyong</name>
        <age>31</age>
        <dob>31/8/1982</dob>
        <income>200,000</income>
    </record>


<record refId="1002">
        <name>kkwong</name>
        <age>30</age>
        <dob>26/7/1983</dob>
        <income>100,999</income>
    </record>

    <record refId="1003">
        <name>joel</name>
        <age>29</age>
        <dob>21/8/1984</dob>
        <income>1,000,000</income>
    </record>
   . . . . . . 
</company>
```

Spring batch Config.

```
parent="basedStep">
        <batch:description>For sending out alerts</batch:description>
        <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="cam.ingestedFile.reader" processor="cam.ingestion.pps.processor" retry-limit="3" commit-interval="1" skip-limit="${batch.tolerance.skip.limit}" > 

             <skippable-exception-classes>
                <include class="com.cam.exception.EBNoAcknowledgementException"/>                   
            </skippable-exception-classes>      
            <retryable-exception-classes>
                <include class="com.cam.exception.EBNoAcknowledgementException"/>
            </retryable-exception-classes>
        </chunk>        
            <transaction-attributes isolation="READ_COMMITTED" ></transaction-attributes>
        </tasklet>

    </batch:step>
```

Comment: sorry, but I can't understand the point. Did you try run the job? Which was the result?

Comment: when i run the job, it restarts from the very start.. i was it to retry on where it fails and proceed ahead...

Comment: are you sure your custom reader is designed to manage stream restartability (eg. ItemStream implementation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified the reader to following and it worked :

```
<bean id="cam.ingestedFile.reader"class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="record" />
```